How to optimally stretch and uniformize 1-dimensional integer points?
The data:
Let X be an array of labeled integers roughly in the domain [0, 2000000]. The size |X| is around 3000 elements. The labels are in the domain [A, B, C].
For example: [(13, A), (16, B), (32, A), (84, C), ...]

The constraints:
Every data point can be moved by ±50 on the axis, but the final ordering must respect the following criteria:

The integer values must remain in increasing order;
The labels must remain in the same order as the initial array.
The integer values must remain integers, no floats.


The goal:
There are 2 metrics to optimize with variable weight:

The variance of the integers, to minimize. (Weighted strongly, say 1.0)
The average distance of the integers, to maximize. (Weighted lightly, say 0.1)


What I've tried:
I initially went for scipy.optimize.minimize() but turns out that doesn't work on integer-only:
def stretch_optimization(initial_array: np.ndarray, weight_variance=1.0, weight_average=0.1):
    ms_data = initial_array[:, 0]
    
    def objective_function(ms_data):
        gaps = np.diff(ms_data)
    
        # Get gaps variance, we want the gaps to be as uniform as possible.
        gaps_variance = np.var(gaps)
    
        # Get gaps average, we want to maximize the gaps size.
        gaps_average = np.mean(gaps)
    
        return weight_variance * gaps_variance - weight_average * gaps_average
    
    bounds = [(ms - 50, ms + 50) for ms, _ in initial_array]
    
    def order_constraint(ms):
        return np.diff(ms)
    
    constraints = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': order_constraint}]
    
    result: np.ndarray = minimize(objective_function, ms_data, bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)

I'm not entirely sure where to go from there. I read that maybe I should use scipy.optimize.milp (?) but it's not clear to me what I should do with that.

What do you mean "doesn't work on integer-only"? Integers can be converted to floats and your requirement that the output be integers is trivially resolved by, for example, rounding the output values and converting to integers.

@Ouroborus You mean I can round the values of ms_data directly in the objective function?

In any case, I'm not getting results that make sense. After running for a few minutes, it spits out the same array as the initial one and the optimization result object's message is that is completed successfully.

IIUC, np.mean(gaps) is gonna be dependent only on first and last element values. Sum of (positive) diffs works like that.

Not sure if this will give best variance, but I would try treating all numbers as positions of identical objects with some mass, connected by same type of strings. Those strings want to "stabilize" whole system. And we also have +-50 constraints that are some walls-like boundaries. Something like this

@dankal444 Ahh that would make sense (re: gaps mean), I guess naturally it's just optimal to put the first and last element on their respective min/max bound and the major part of the optimization is gonna be about the variance. Interesting physics approach too, I'll see if I can apply that.

Maybe you can use pulp module:
Example with array of 20 variables (from 0 to 100, contstraint is +/-5):
import pulp
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
# X = np.sort(np.random.randint(0, 2_000_000, size=3000))
X = np.sort(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=20))

prob = pulp.LpProblem("stretch", pulp.LpMinimize)

# amounts to add to each variable (to be computed):
variables = [
    # pulp.LpVariable(f"x{i:04}", lowBound=-50, upBound=50, cat="Integer")
    pulp.LpVariable(f"x{i:04}", lowBound=-5, upBound=5, cat="Integer")
    for i, v in enumerate(X)
]

maximize_average_gap_size = pulp.LpVariable("maximize_average_gap_size")
minimize_variance = pulp.LpVariable("minimize_variance")

# out problem: miniminize variance and maximize gap size
prob += (minimize_variance * 1.0) - (maximize_average_gap_size * 0.1)

gaps = [
    ((X[idx] + variables[idx]) - (X[idx - 1] + variables[idx - 1]))
    for idx in range(1, len(variables))
]
mean_gaps = pulp.lpSum(gaps) / len(gaps)

# define "maximize_average_gap_size"
prob += maximize_average_gap_size == mean_gaps

abs_minimize_variance = pulp.LpVariable("minimize_variance")

abs_vars = []
for i, g in enumerate(gaps):
    abs_var = pulp.LpVariable(f"abs_var_{i:04}")
    prob += (g - mean_gaps) <= abs_var
    prob += -(g - mean_gaps) <= abs_var
    abs_vars.append(abs_var)

# define "minimize_variance" (as sum of absolute values)
prob += minimize_variance == pulp.lpSum(abs_vars)

# constraint: every next value after adding has to be greater or equal than before
for idx in range(1, len(variables)):
    prob += (X[idx - 1] + variables[idx - 1]) <= (X[idx] + variables[idx])

prob.solve()

# print(pulp.LpStatus[prob.status])
# for v in prob.variables():
#     print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)

print("BEFORE:")
print(X)

gaps_before = np.diff(X)
print(f"{np.var(gaps_before)=}")
print(f"{np.mean(gaps_before)=}")

print("AFTER:")
after = [int(x + v.value()) for x, v in zip(X, variables)]
print(after)
gaps_after = np.diff(after)
print(f"{np.var(gaps_after)=}")
print(f"{np.mean(gaps_after)=}")

Prints:
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver                                                                                                                                                                
Version: 2.10.3                                                                                                                                                                               
Build Date: Dec 15 2019 


... 

BEFORE:                                                                                        
[ 1  2 14 20 21 23 29 37 51 52 60 71 74 74 82 86 87 87 92 99]
np.var(gaps_before)=np.float64(17.185595567867033)                                                                                                                                            
np.mean(gaps_before)=np.float64(5.157894736842105)                                                                                                                                            
AFTER:                                                                                         
[2, 7, 12, 18, 23, 28, 34, 40, 46, 54, 60, 66, 69, 74, 77, 82, 87, 92, 97, 102]                                                                                                               
np.var(gaps_after)=np.float64(1.1412742382271468)      
np.mean(gaps_after)=np.float64(5.2631578947368425)                                        


It's really interesting how the "1" became "2" in order to minimize the variance. That looks promising though I'll give it a shot. Hopefully it works with thousands of data points.

Wait are you actually able to run this with the X = np.sort(np.random.randint(0, 2_000_000, size=3000)) data? I ran it with my 6000 data points and it's still running after 15-20 minutes.
